# I have reached the max number of classes in a VB6 project, any solution?

Tags: dll, vb6, project

I have a huge legacy VB6 DLL project that have many classes. When I want to add 1 more class to the project, an error message "Out of memory" was shown. I have tried to create another DLL project and move some classes to the new one but failed because of another "circular reference problem" occur. My classes are reference to each others. I know I can use late binding to solve the "circular reference" problem but I don't want to do that because there are too many code have to be changed and all code intelligence are gone. Please help. Thanks

[image: Added a diagram to show my current situation (black), and my expected solution (blue) but don't know how. The red one is technically ok but not good because same category classes putting in different dll projects]

[Update] Just added a diagram to show my current situation (black), and my expected solution (blue) but don't know how. The red one is technically ok but not good because same category classes putting in different dll projects

Comment: Late-binding does not solve circular references. VB6 projects can hold up to 32000 "identifiers" (incl. forms, classes, etc.) so this is a hard limit. I would come up with common interfaces to consume (not concrete classes) so that the implementing classes can be easily spread out in different projects.

Comment: Thanks for your idea, wqw May I have more details about how common interface works ? Do you mean putting different classes into 1 general class ? and then calling those original methods through a general function method with variant parameters ?

Comment: Classes in `a` which reference classes in `b` could instead reference an interface which is then implemented by `b` so that there are no `Dim var As b` in the code of `a` but only `Dim var As IMyService` which are declared in a common "interface-only" DLL referenced both by `a` and `b`. This way `a` and `b` does not reference each other and can be separated in different DLLs.

Comment: Sorry that I am not fully understand as I am not familiar with interface inheritance. In `a`, when I declare `Dim var as IMyService`, even `b` implements `IMyService` class, how can `a` get the logics in `b` ? while `b` is a separated DLL and `a` references `IMyService` DLL only. Can you give me an example or any web link ? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Just to clarify, this is crashing when the program isn't running?  I've heard (https://forums.codeguru.com/showthread.php?19819-Is-there-a-maximum-number-of-classes-in-VB5) that there may be a 255 class limit, but I've never encountered it personally...  If **ALL** of your classes are so tightly intertwined that NONE of them can be extricated to somewhere else, even in groups, I would suggest your program likely suffers some serious design issues..  Usually there is SOME hierarchy that can be analyzed.  You may have to use stages..  DLL1, and then DLL2 uses DLL1, which the program uses?

Comment: I have around 850 classes in 1 DLL. It is not crashing but cannot add any 1 more class. Yes, I agree there are some serious design issues but I guess I can't change the structure too much. Yes, I have tried to move some classes from DLL1 to DLL2 to release more rooms but failed because many of those classes are reference to each other. Moving some classes to DLL2 will cause circular reference problem. That's what I am asking for help. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

As a first step, I would look for dead code that could just be removed. This might be the quickest way to clear the immediate problem by freeing up space for new classes/identifiers. This would buy you time to more carefully refactor into independent projects.

MZTools is a (non-free) VB6 IDE plugin which has (IIRC) some tools to do basic code inspections and find modules, procedures, etc. which are not referenced. So that right there might get you what you need, if its not already obvious which things you could just delete from the project.

---

BTW if you aren't using source control I think that would be essential for this kind of work. You want to first commit the current state, and then you know you have that as a safe reference point to base further changes upon.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. You really understand my situation. Actually I was doing this way in the past several months to survive. Instead of using 3rd party plugin, I have even spent many hours to write another program (also vb6 ^_^) to check every class every line of code in project to find out those dead code/classes. As you said, this helps buying time but now I come to the last minute and want to have a "comparatively" long term solution. Thanks again.